# how can set where condition in list() method in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using list() method to get the data.

```
<g:select id="complaint" class="form-control chosen-select" multiple="true" name="complaint" from="${settings.Complaint.list()}"optionKey="id" optionValue="name"/>
```

Now I would like get the data as list which status is active. Is there any way to use condition in list()?

Comment: Take a look at [createCriteria](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) or [namedQueries](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html)

Comment: Or more generally, [Querying with GORM](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying).

Comment: Thanks it is working after using createCriteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def c = vaccination.VaccineBrand.createCriteria()
    def vaccineBrandList = c.list {
        eq("status", "Active")
    }
```